# Design pattern to limit access to a shared resource

Tags: java, design-patterns, distributed-system

Problem statement

At start up multiple machines will become online. There is a scheduler that will run on each of those machine. The scheduler will Fire every 5 minutes on each machine. There will he bunch of data to read from Cassandra. However only one machine must read those messages from Cassandra and must delete the messages after it’s done. Two or more machines reading/processing the same data will cause undesired load on the downstream system.

Possible solutions:

Use zookeeper to implement a distributed lock.
Perhaps make use of Leader election design pattern.
Shared resource design pattern also work in the same way.
Modified leaky bucket design pattern which can work with distributed application

Is there a design pattern which can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: How about using a master-slave architecture where the master runs the job on a schedule and distributes the task to the slaves, partitioning the data to be processed by a key. Scheduling happens on a single machine.

Comment: Ah yes Master Slave architecture! Spring Batch already lets you do that. However, how do you decide who is going to be the master? I don't want to make the call at start up time... Also what if the Master fails? How do i elect another master. In my application all the machines are like peers. I have to dynamically choose one of the machine to process the messages. After five minutes, the process repeats. I have to select a new machine to process the message.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Spring Cloud Dataflow, checkout an example [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/batch/file-ingest).

Comment: Seems like spring cloud data flow is an evolution of Spring batch. But they have the same problem as spring batch. Run few servers as masters and run the remaining servers in worker configuration. I want to run all the servers as same and decide at runtime who can be a master and who can be a worker

Comment: Queue your requests for a particular resource? The first request will be served, the resource would be delete. All the other requests will returns a resource not found error or something, that you can handle.